# OnBecameInvisible not functioning as required

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am running into strange problem with Unity3d's OnBecameInvisible().

As expected this function should be triggered on the Game objects mesh renderer when it leaves the camera bounds but it gets called when i exit the play mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OnBecameInvisible does get called even when you exit play mode. This is as expected because at this point, the Renderers are no longer being rendered by the camera in play mode.

Further, OnBecameInvisible & OnBecameVisible are also called by the scene view camera. Therefore, if your renderer is no longer visible to the **play** mode camera, it might still be visible to the **scene** mode camera.

[OnBecameInvisible](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnBecameInvisible.html) from Unity docs. See the quote below

> When running in the editor, scene view cameras will also cause this function to be called.